# MS Access 2013: How to open tables in new tab?

Tags: microsoft-access

In MS access 2013, if you open multiple tables, it should open like this, by default

[image]

Something happened to my access DB and now tables are being opened in new window, how to restore the default preferences and let tables open in new tabs instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Options under "Current Database".

[image]